# How to run list of linux commands as different user

Tags: linux, shell, unix, ubuntu

I have to execute list of commands as different user than the one i am currently logged in.
I tried the below script, it works fine but bundle install gets stuck and doesn't come out.

```
sudo -u maneesh bash -c : && RUNAS="sudo -u maneesh"
$RUNAS bash<<_
cd /opt/maneesh/

unicorn_config="/opt/maneesh/config/unicorn.rb"

bundle install

bundle exec unicorn_rails -D -p 9001  -c $unicorn_config
```

_

Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: What do you mean with get stuck? Shouldn't you solve that problem then?

Comment: If I login as maneesh user, bundle install works just fine. but when I login as different user and  execute the above script bundle install gets stuck

Comment: Are you sure it's the bundle installer? I don't know much about ruby or unicorn, but the `-p` flags seems to look like you're running a server. A server normally "gets stuck" it waits until clients ask information, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Well in order to run a command as a different user, you can simply list the comands with comma-dot's and run them in bash mode:

```
sudo -u maneesh bash -c 'cd /opt/maneesh/; unicorn_config="/opt/maneesh/config/unicorn.rb"; bundle install; bundle exec unicorn_rails -D -p 9001  -c $unicorn_config'
```

---

Or you could simply write a shell script:

**`list.sh`** (or some other name):

```
cd /opt/maneesh/
unicorn_config="/opt/maneesh/config/unicorn.rb"
bundle install
bundle exec unicorn_rails -D -p 9001  -c $unicorn_config
```

and run this as another user:

```
sudo -u maneesh bash list.sh
```

I think your script probably fails on the `cd /opt/maneesh` where only the specified user has access. You can solve this by changing access rights.

Comment: Actually I cannot run like this, have to handle this with in the script itself. I know it sounds weird, but if i have to explain that it will be a big story.  Is there a way we can handle this within the script itself ?

Comment: I added below lines in a file called list.sh                                                         sudo -u maneesh bash -c 'cd /opt/maneesh/; unicorn_config="/opt/maneesh/config/unicorn.rb"; bundle install; bundle exec unicorn_rails -D -p 9001  -c $unicorn_config' and executed the script. But it gets stuck at Fetching  source lines. This was the same error i mentioned earlier as well                                                                                       ./list.sh
Fetching source index for https://rubygems.org/

Comment: apparently sudo -u maneesh bash -c 'cd /opt/abc; bundle install' itself is not working correctly :(

Comment: As a work around: login in a `tty` (Ctrl+Alt+F1), log in with `maneesh` and execute the script there...